# PHP: Advice on gantt-type chart

Tags: php, mysql, charts

I have an app that I've developed that has time entries. The time entries have a start date (datetime), an end date(datetime), and are associated with a task. Time entries typically range from a couple of minutes to a couple of hours and would be being recorded during the day. Each time-entry has a description.

The type of chart I want to create would be similar to a gantt chart. It would show a days time range, ranging from the time of the start of the first time entry to the end date of the last.

```
        8am       9am   9:15am   10:05am

Task 1 |----------                     --

Task 2 |          -----          --

Task 3 |               ----------  ----
```

I've used fusioncharts but I'd like to move away from them. Has anyone created a chart similar to this one that can give me some advice?

Thanks in advance,

Billy

Comment: Be more specific: what is wrong with those frameworks? What exactly do you need? Do you have any constraint?

Comment: Oh it's just that I don't want to pay for a licence for the paid fusioncharts and the free fusion charts look somewhat outdated. So really I guess it's an open source charting solution I'm looking for. I'd like it to be small enough to fit 450 x 300px. Also, if you were to hover over the bars, it would display the amount of time (which I can calculate)

Comment: You can quite easily write something like this with pure css. You might also want to add some more functionality like dragging etc with javascript. Actually kinda fun creating:) Of course it's a question about how much time you wish to spend on it too.. if it's for a client project or something making one yourself is a waste of time. As for readymade solutions I haven't really seen too many that isn't complete project manager packages, but I'm sure there's something out there.

Answer (score 1):

The best Javascript tool I know of for this sort of thing is [Timeline](http://www.simile-widgets.org/timeline/).

The example on the above link shows it mainly being used for points in time, but it can also be used for periods of time as per a gantt chart. (scroll around the example to see some)

It's a Javascript tool, but you should be able to use PHP or another language to populate the data into it.

Oh, and it's open source as well.  :-)

Hope that helps.

Comment: The Timeline tool looks pretty awesome but I thnk it's a bit overkill for what I'm looking for. More of a fixed graph going form 8am - 5pm sorta thing.